# afterinsert not displaying me.ID

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a form where I'm trying to do the following:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    MsgBox ("The ID value is " & Me.ID)  ''Name of autonumber field
End Sub
```

Problem is, no message is coming up after I insert a new record on the form.

I do, however, get a popup message when I save asking if I want to save the record named "xxxxxxx".  Why is it not displaying the recordID?

Comment: Did you put a break point into your function and debugged it if the program does run this function after insertion is done ?

Comment: I'll be completely honest I'm very new to ms access and no idea how to debug.  If you mean by break point the line between private functions it is there and it recognizes it in the form properties.  Theres an afterupdate which does fire so I'm wondering if the afterupdate is firing and prevending the afterinsert?

Comment: think I found the problem in part.  Me.ID only works if the ID column is labelled "ID" in my case it's labelled applicationId so I'm guessing I should be doing Me.applicationId

Comment: No idea why but adding a new value is coming as an update not an insert.  Probably the legacy code.  Anyways, I've found my way around it :)